# Extract font and its corresponding cmap in PDF

Tags: pdf

I am tried several ways to extract font from pdf viz. fontforge, mupdf, pdfparser in C# and also some pythone script. But am just confusing about get exact pair of a font and its cmap embeded in pdf. Please direct me the right approach by which i will get exact pairs of fonts and its cmaps.

Comment: The right place to start looking is the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). That in combination with a PDF library that allows you to access low-level PDF objects (e.g. [iText and iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/)) allows you to match embedded fonts and PDF CMaps and extract them. If you tell us more about the requirements you have, detailed answers may come. BTW, you are aware that depending on the font in question you may have to acquire some license to be allowed to use the data for anything but PDF display.

Comment: thanks @mkl: i am not going to use the font for any recreation or something. Actually i am dealing with pdf having unicode-font and more complexity is the font is subset font. While copying data from pdf it looses some characters and replaces with basic charater which damages the copied data. So i want to analyse the where cmap has got wrong entries for a particular font. So need a pair of cmap used in pdf and its font.

Comment: When you say "copying data", do you mean by copy & paste from a viewer to another application? In that case a missing or troublesome toUnicode mapping might also be the culprit.

Comment: @mkl yes i know the troublesome toUnicode mapping causing a problem so now for further investigation i need font and its toUnicode used in pdf

Comment: Yes someone gave this an up-vote. It is a good question; needs a more detailed answer than the one given, problem is that any good answer will be very specific to an application or piece of software.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my first comment, that should be easy using [iText or iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/) or any other such library that allows you to access low-level PDF objects.

In case of iText(Sharp), [ListUsedFonts.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=287) and [ListUsedFonts.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter16&ex=ListUsedFonts) can present starting points for you; they inspect all the font dictionaries in a PDF file accessible via at least one page. Instead of the simple output of those examples, simply export all the information you need. For this, [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) should be your reference guide.